# how to do partitioning on VARCHAR column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
        (ID int, STATUS varchar(1))
    ;

    INSERT INTO @Table1
        (ID, STATUS)
    VALUES
        (1,  'A'),
        (1,  'A'),
        (1,  'A'),
        (1,  'B'),
        (1,  'A'),
        (2,  'C'),
        (2,  'C')
    ;
```

**Script :**

```
Select *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY STATUS ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))RN from @Table1
```

**Getting Result Set**

```
ID  STATUS  RN
1   A       1
1   A       2
1   A       3
1   A       4
1   B       1
2   C       1
2   C       2
```

**Need Output**

```
ID  STATUS  RN
1   A       1
1   A       2
1   A       3
1   B       1
1   A       1
2   C       1
2   C       2
```

Comment: i want like that.. above result is getting for my query and where Output what i want is i have posted last

Comment: It looks like you're assuming that the rows in the table stay in the order in which they were inserted and will be returned in that order, There is no such guarantee. Unless you explicitly order the rows, e.g. with an identity column in the table and an `ORDER BY` clause in queries, you may get rows back in any order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
        (ID int, STATUS varchar(1));

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (ID, STATUS)
VALUES
    (1,  'A'),
    (1,  'A'),
    (1,  'A'),
    (1,  'B'),
    (1,  'A'),
    (2,  'C'),
    (2,  'C');

;WITH Tmp
AS 
(    
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNumber FROM @Table1
)


SELECT
    A.ID ,
    A.STATUS ,      
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.STATUS, (A.RowNumber - A.RN)  ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
FROM
(
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STATUS ORDER BY RowNumber) AS RN from tmp

) A
ORDER BY
    A.RowNumber
```

Output:

```
ID          STATUS RN
----------- ------ ------
1           A      1
1           A      2
1           A      3
1           B      1
1           A      1
2           C      1
2           C      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, In the insert statement that you posted. How is 4 different from 1,2 and 3, if it is based on a different column then include that column as well in "row_number" in partition by sub clause. Because otherwise it will think that 'A' in 4 and 'A' in 1,2,3 are same and therefore group them together.

```
INSERT INTO @Table1
  (ID, STATUS)
VALUES
  (1,  'A'),   <--  1
  (1,  'A'),   <--  2
  (1,  'A'),   <--  3
  (1,  'B'),
  (1,  'A'),   <--  4
  (2,  'C'),
  (2,  'C')
;
```